# условие в циклах ,СИ

Tags: c

Что означает выражение в скобках: while **( *pStrWordHead )** или например **( ! *pWrd)**

Comment: А какая из частей вам не понятна? Цикл while? Разыменование указателя? Проверка значения на 0? Логическое отрицание?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Внутри while так же как и внутри if все рассматриваться как логическое выражение. для которого ноль (двоичный, он же 0x00) рассматриваться как *ложь*, любое другое значение как *истина*.

*pStrWordHead - это значение по адресу на который сейчас указывает указатель pStrWordHead. Т.е. если это указатель на строку - то первый символ этой строки.

Следовательно `while(*pStrWordHead)` работает до тех пор пока `pStrWordHead` указывает на ненулевой байт. `!` - это *НЕ* т.е. он дает *истину* когда `pWrd` указывает на 0. В строках C двоичный ноль означает конец строки.

Если вы с массивами уже освоились и так проще, то: `while(*pStrWordHead)` равнозначно `while(pStrWordHead[0] != 0)`, А `! *pWrd` равнозначно `pWrd[0] == 0`

Comment: Это исходя из предположения, что `pStrWordHead` есть указатель на строку. (Что в принципе похоже на правду, исходя из названия переменной.)

Comment: Спасибо MIke теперь понятно стало